# How to choose the right forecast method for variable 'X' when I have some available forecast for variable 'Y' with historical data of X and Y?

Tags: matlab, regression, forecasting, knn

I have yearly historical data for variables 'X' and 'Y'. Say the time frame is 't'. In addition to available historical data, I also have the forecast data of variable 'Y' for t+1. My aim is to forecast X for t+1. The data quality is sparse. So, could someone recommend which method to start with?

Thanks

So far, I did not get any clue as to how to use the forecast Y data. So, with the historical data, I tried multivariate regression and knn search algorithm. The results were not satisfactory though! I am using MATLAB.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: This question seems more suitable to [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thanks. I will post it on Cross Validated.